# Handling a List of Object in AJAX and Spring

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am not able to parse a list of objects in AJAX, Whenever I try to parse the list, **ERROR code 406** pops. But if I try to send a string it receives fine.

**Controller Code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getstates", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<State> liststates(HttpServletRequest request){
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        List<State> states = adminService.getAllstates(Integer.parseInt(country));
        System.out.println("The states we recieved is" +states);
        String result ="hello Bhaskar "+ country;
        return states;
    }
```

***JSP AJAX Code***

```
var id = $('#select_country').val();
$.ajax({
    url : "getstates",
    data: {country : id},
    dataType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    success : function(response) {
        alert("Access Success "+ response);
        $('#select_country').append("<option value='-1'>Select User</option>");
        for ( var i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var user = response[i];
            $('#select_country').append("<option value=\"" + user.id + "\">" + user.state+ "</option>");
    }

    },
    error : function(response) {
        alert("Access Fail "+ response);
    }
```

*** Browser Output***      Access Failed [object Object]

[Open Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFrow.png)

*** Console Output***

The states we received is [in.complit.model.State@7dee7dc6, in.complit.model.State@54263ffc, in.complit.model.State@43e78960, in.complit.model.State@4ce669b5]

Comment: Check if your maven dependency has jackson mapper jar added . You can check by mvn dependency:tree

Refer this https://coderanch.com/t/650827/frameworks/acceptable-message-AJAX-call-Spring

Comment: Yes, it is already added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem Solved by adding a ***try-catch block*** while calling the service class method in the ***Controller*** Class. The code after adding it is as shown below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getstates", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<State> liststates(HttpServletRequest request){
        //List<Country> listCountries = adminService.getAllcountries();
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        List<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();
         try {
                states = adminService.getAllstates(Integer.parseInt(country));
         }catch(Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
         }
        System.out.println("The Country We Recieved "+ country);
        System.out.println("The states we recieved is" +states);
        return states;
    }
```